# Does the intersection of bases of different topologies form a base of some other topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let's say $\mathcal{B}_1, \mathcal{B}_2$ are two bases for topologies $\mathcal{T}_1, \mathcal{T}_2$ of a space $X$, respectively. My question is whether $\mathcal{B}_1 \cap\mathcal{B}_2$ is a base for some topology? I can't think of a counter example so I went for the natural choice as I claim that it is a base for $\mathcal{T}_1 \cap \mathcal{T}_2$.

To proceed, I let $U\in\mathcal{T}_1 \cap \mathcal{T}_2$ and $x\in U\subset X$. Since $U\in \mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_1$ is a base of $\mathcal{T}_1$, there exists $V_1\in\mathcal{B}_1$ such that $x\in V_1\subset U$. Similarly, there exists $V_2\in\mathcal{B}_2$ such that $x\in V_2 \subset U$. Then I stuck here because there is no guarantee that I can choose an open set $V\subset V_1\cap V_2$ in $\mathcal{B}_1 \cap\mathcal{B}_2$ containing $x$.

*Remark: The definition I used for base is: If $\mathcal{B}$ is a subset of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ such that each $U\in\mathcal{T}$ can be written as an arbitrary union $U=\cup C$ with every $C\in\mathcal{B}$.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal{B}_1:=\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q,\,a<b\}$, $\mathcal{B}_2:=\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb Q,\,a<b\}$. Both are bases for the standard topology on $\Bbb R$. However, we clearly have $\mathcal{B}_1\cap\mathcal{B}_2=\emptyset$ which is not a basis of any topology on $\Bbb R$, nevermind the topology $T_1\cap T_2=T$ the usual Euclidean topology.